# How do I do a 301 redirect because of duplicate urls

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am currently trying to do a 301 redirect for all the pages of a site i am working on. The problem is that this url:

```
http://site.com/cash/ 
http://site.com/credit/
```

and

```
http://site.com/cash 
http://site.com/credit
```

display the same pages

This will result in a number of duplicate URL issues and start splitting your PageRank of our SEO.

I was trying to do that on my site where all the seo points to the non-slash version

BTW I have about 90 pages that i have to change...any ideas on a good way of achieving this

How do i do a 301 redirect in the htaccess to do this on all my pages

**Edit:**

So to understand correctly. this will do the 301 redirect

```
# Remove the trailing slash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But how does this exclude folder1

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

and would i put that in the same htaccess file or create another htaccess file in the folder1 directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following to your `.htaccess` to remove the trailing slash

```
# Remove the trailing slash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Update**

You can then choose to also add `www`

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com$1 [R=301]
```

or remove it

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: does this redirect on example.com/ because on the third line i see the R=301 which is the 301 redirect but it has a www ...does that matter

Comment: @Tamer: I added an update with two additional rules which you can use to either enforce or remove `www`.

Comment: there is a problem with this logic because all the folders example.com/folder1/ or example.com/folder2/ will not render at all

Comment: so maybe i can do the ones i need...how what i do one for example like example.com/change_me/ to example.com/change_me ...beasically i was wondering how to change just this one

Comment: You can use `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` to exclude requests for files / folders that you're not rewriting.

Comment: ok so for example would i put that snippet in the .htaccess of the folder1 directory and would i paste both

Comment: Since it's a _directory_, I'm afraid removing the trailing slash isn't an option.

Comment: @stealthyninja let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2497/discussion-between-tamer-and-stealthyninja)

Comment: If you click on the dicussion link we can chat please

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a 301, you could just use a [rel canonical link](http://www.google.com/support/webmasters/bin/answer.py?answer=139394).

Comment: I am doing that as well but i was reading that it maybe better to do both...does that sound true

Comment: +1 for this answer; @Tamer: I think (and use it myself as well) canonical links would be the way to go, even if just to use in conjunction with other redirects.

Comment: Both are best, as some search engines might not support canonical links, but in reality just a canonical link will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *<shudder>* mod_rewrite instead, if it's for an Apache server... It's disasterously inefficient but probably the best option if what you're bothered about is SEO

Comment: Without a single link to reputable source(s) on why _mod_rewrite_ is "disastrously inefficient", I'm not sure why you made that throw-away _comment_ in an _answer_. ಠ_ಠ

Comment: @stealthyninja Sorry, that is a fair comment and I do try to be better than that... The problem with mod_rewrite is that 1) It has to evaluate a regex on *every* request at least once, which on heavy-trafficked web servers, specially shared boxes, eats valuable CPU time. 2) Every request runs through mod_rewrite *at least twice*, sometimes many more if the rules were written by someone who didn't 100% know how to do it (see the [L] flag) which eats yet more CPU. All this behaviour is documented [in the mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).